# Apple Pay and Stripe: Token not being sent to Stripe

Tags: ios, stripe-payments, applepay

Set up Apple Pay in my app and it seems to work fine when running on device.  Using Stripe as the payment processor but it is not sending the token to Stripe, but seems to be charging the credit card listed in my iPhone's digital wallet.

The problem I am having is that once I press the "Pay with Touch ID", I get a check mark in my Apple Pay sheet but the following page appears in Xcode:

[image: error]

**Code for Apple Pay & Stripe**

```
    var paymentSucceeded: Bool = false


func paymentAuthorizationViewController(_ controller: PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController,
                                        didAuthorizePayment payment: PKPayment, completion: @escaping (PKPaymentAuthorizationStatus) -> Void) {

    STPAPIClient.shared().createToken(with: payment) { (token, error) in
        print("I am here")

            if error != nil {
                completion(.failure)
                print("failed")

            } else {
                self.paymentSucceeded = true
                completion(.success)
                print("woohoo")
            }

            self.createBackendCharge(with: token!, completion: completion)
            print("created Backend Charge")
            self.postStripeToken(token: token!)
            print("posted stripe token")

    }

} // paymentAuthorizationViewController( didAuthorizePayment )


func createBackendCharge(with token: STPToken, completion: @escaping (_: PKPaymentAuthorizationStatus) -> Void) {
    //We are printing Stripe token here, you can charge the Credit Card using this token from your backend.
    print("Stripe Token is \(token)")
    completion(.success)

} // createBackendCharge func



func paymentAuthorizationViewControllerDidFinish(_ controller: PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController) {

    controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
        if (self.paymentSucceeded) {
            // show a receipt page
        }
    })

} // paymentAuthorizationViewControllerDidFinish()


    @IBAction func applePayPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

    // we have already accepted the request from viewDriverBids
    // all that remains is to complete payment

    print("enable apple pay")

    // send user to Apple Pay to make payment

    let paymentNetworks = [PKPaymentNetwork.visa, .masterCard, .interac, .discover, .amex]

    if PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController.canMakePayments(usingNetworks: paymentNetworks) {
        paymentRequest = PKPaymentRequest()
        paymentRequest.currencyCode = "CAD"
        paymentRequest.countryCode = "CA"
        paymentRequest.merchantIdentifier = "merchant.com.xxx"
        paymentRequest.supportedNetworks = paymentNetworks
        paymentRequest.merchantCapabilities = .capability3DS
        paymentRequest.requiredShippingAddressFields = [.all]
        paymentRequest.paymentSummaryItems = self.rydes()

        let applePayVC = PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController(paymentRequest: paymentRequest)
        applePayVC.delegate = self
        self.present(applePayVC, animated: true, completion: {

            rRydeHandler.Instance.completeApplePay()

            self.paymentComplete = true
            self.updateDriverInfoView()
        })

    }  else {

        print("Tell the user they need to set up Apple Pay!")
    }

} // applePayPressed func ACTION
```

**backend server func**

```
func postStripeToken(token: STPToken) {

    let URL = "http://localhost/donate/payment.php"
    let params = ["stripeToken": token.tokenId,
                  "amount": Int(self.driverInfoView.rydeFare.text!)!,
                  "currency": "cad",
                  "description": self.riderName] as [String : Any]

    let manager = AFHTTPSessionManager()
    manager.post(URL, parameters: params, success: { (operation, responseObject) -> Void in

        if let response = responseObject as? [String: String] {

            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: response["status"], message: response["message"], preferredStyle: .alert)

            let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
            alertController.addAction(defaultAction)

            self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

    }) { (operation, error) -> Void in
        self.handleError(error as NSError)
        print(error)
    }
}
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable exception breakpoints then Xcode should crash on the line that is causing the issue.

It is almost certainly caused by one of the `!` in your code.

Force unwrapping values is very dangerous. It's always better and safer to unwrap it in a `guard let` or `if let`.

Comment: Thanks for answering.  I put some breakpoints in, I am thinking it has something to do with the backend server function, but I'm not sure what.

Comment: Would be helpful if you could find out exactly which line is causing the crash.

Comment: It seems that have Fabric installed was interfering with sending the token.  All is well again.